# Why is the jframe not being cleared?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

This is a weird situation.I delete the contents of a frame and add new content.
But the **old** content is being added twice.Why is this happening?
This might seem like very long code,but most of it is generating the content for frame.
The problem, as I see starts when the ***manager()*** function is being called from *ActionListener* of ***addUserFrame()*** function.

```
public class adminManager {
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static JFrame f;
    private static JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
    private static JButton addUser,exitTest,addTest,editTest;   

    public static void manager(JFrame frame)
   {
    f=frame;f.setSize(400,800);
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Dimension d = new Dimension(100,30);
    addUser = new JButton("ADD USER");
    exitTest = new JButton("EXIT");
    addTest =  new JButton("ADD TEST");
    editTest = new JButton("EDIT TEST");
    p.add(addUser);p.add(addTest);
    p.add(editTest);p.add(exitTest);
    f.setTitle("Select Option");
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(p);   
    f.setVisible(true);     
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    bindEvents();
  }

    public static void addUserFrame(JFrame f)
   {        
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();J
    Panel parentPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Enter User-Name");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Enter Password");
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton back = new JButton("Go Back");
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    p3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    parentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(parentPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    p1.setSize(200,100);
    p2.setSize(200,100);
    p3.setSize(200,100);
    p1.add(l1);p1.add(t1);
    p2.add(l2);p2.add(t2);
    p3.add(btn);p3.add(back);
    parentPanel.add(p1);parentPanel.add(p2);parentPanel.add(p3);
    f.add(parentPanel);
    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){             
            f.getContentPane().removeAll();f.repaint();
            manager(f);             
        }
    });

}

public static void bindEvents(){
    addUser.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            f.getContentPane().removeAll();
            f.repaint();    
            addUserFrame(f);
            f.setSize(400, 150);
            f.setTitle("Add User");
            f.setVisible(true);             
        }
    });
    }

public static void main(String []args){
    manager(new JFrame());
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Solved by moving `p=new JPanel()` into `manager()` method

Comment: (1-) I'm sure you don't write code with multiple statements on every line making the code impossible to read and maintain. So don't expect us to read code like that in the forum. Post properly formatted code.

Comment: @camickr done.now let's see if you can answer it

Comment: Also, abide by the Java language conventions: class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: That's not what @camickr was saying, he meant this: `p.add(addUser);p.add(addTest);` why 2 statements on the same line? He wasn't referring to the curly braces on same line as `if () {` but those I showed you!

Comment: @Frakcool thanks for the help.my mistake and a silly one.solved it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle yup.solved. was just moving it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> f.getContentPane().removeAll();
> ```

you remove the Panel `p` from the frame but in method `manager()` you add the same `p` where you added the new elements to. You must either call `clear()` on `p` or create a new Panel `p`

Comment: The old content is being displayed twice

Comment: @Pradeep please enhance the code in your question to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the same JPanel is being used.
Solved it by moving `p=new JPanel()` into `manager()` method